# Probability of sequence of estimated values belonging to a set

Tags: pr.probability, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Suppose I have estimated residuals of an ARCH(1) process: $\hat{\varepsilon}_1, \dots, \hat{\varepsilon}_n$ from the sample of length $n$. On the other hand, I have "true" residuals: $\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0, 1)$, let's denote "true" CDF by $F(x)$.

**Problem:** I want to show, that for any sequence of sets $A_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the following convergence holds:

$$|P([\hat{\varepsilon}_1, \dots, \hat{\varepsilon}_n] \in A_n) - P([\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_n] \in A_n)| \to 0, n \to \infty.$$

**Thoughts:**

1. From [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02595704) I know that empirical CDF converges to $F$: $|\hat{F}_n(x) - F(x)| \to 0, n \to \infty$;
2. I also know that the value in problem is bounded by $\sum^n_{i=1} P(\hat{\varepsilon}_i \neq \varepsilon_i)$

I cannot understand how to prove this convergence when residuals are treated as multivariate random variable... It would be great if there would exist any upper bound for value in the problem in terms of coordinates (i.e., their CDF, so that convergence (1) could be applied).

On the other hand (in case of using bound (2)), I do not have ideas how to prove that this sum converges to 0...